# Json Parsing + operator is neglated

Tags: java, json, spring, date, datetime

I am parsing JSON String date to java date object. The date format contains the timezone. eg. `20141025201010+0000`  when I try to parse the string to java util date object, the Jsong string contain '+' operator considers it as blank space and i get string as `20141025201010 0000` where `0000` is timezone. so when i convert it in to date object including timezone it is giving error. so any idea how I can parse the String date including timezone to Java Date object

Comment: How exactly are you parsing the JSON? Providing a code example would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like a url encoding issue. `+` is treated as a space. If you put https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ABC+PQR you get "ABC PQR".

Comment: @UtkarshBhavsar you have to urlencode your parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring MVC then spring itself takes care of decoding the encoded string. You need not decode it again as if you pass `20141024201010%2B0000` which is your encoded string for date, Spring will take care of decoding it to `20141025201010+0000` which you require to pass into `SimpleDateFormat` as this pattern:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmssZ
```

Which will parse your date preserving the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `SimpleDateFormat` for this type of work. Have a look on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more understanding.
If you looking out like "0:08 PM, PDT" then "K:mm a, z" format help you to convert the date.